# GlassFish Quandary

Tags: java, macos, jsf, glassfish

I am trying to install GlassFish (on a Mac) as directed by a book on Core JSF. When I go to

```
http://localhost:8080
```

I see the page as displayed in the book, with no problems. However, when I copy the login.war file to the directory specified in the book and try to go to the login page

```
http://localhost:8080/login
```

I simply see a 404 Error.

I /think/ I have copied the file correctly. What does this indicate? By virtue of the fact that I am able to see the page

```
http://localhost:8080
```

correctly does this mean that GlassFish has been appropriately installed? What does the 404 Error likely mean? Thanks. Conor.

Comment: are you getting the app welcome page on http://localhost:8080? or the glassfish server is running page?

Comment: The page contains the text 'Your server is now running' as a main heading, so I guess the latter of the two.

Comment: There is no problem with Glassfish. Make sure your application is deployed. Go to admin control localhost:4848 --> Applications and see if it is deployed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [404](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) error is the HTTP page not found error. This means, the page you are trying to access does not exist. I believe your application is not deployed on the server.

To deploy your application, go to server admin page localhost:4848 click on application from the navigation menu. From there click on Deploy and browse to the file location. You can also specify the context root where your application should be deployed.

However, your application might be deployed on the server with a different context root.

If you have a glassfish descriptor, then you can check your context root from there. However, If you do not have a glassfish descriptor then you need to create one.

In this descriptor you need to define your context root name.

```
<context-root>/foobar</context-root>
```

this means the application will be deployed on `localhost:8080/foobar`

Similarly, if you defined your context root as following:

```
<context-root>/</context-root>
```

Then your application will be deployed on `localhost:8080/`